# Fetch image based on text and display from API react

Tags: reactjs, api, react-router, react-hooks

I've retrieved a list of categories using an API. Now I want to fetch images from an URL based on the categories. I tried using each category to fetch images from another API, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './css/Category.css';

function Category() {

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
        getImage();
    }, []);

    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    const [image, setImage] = useState('');

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const data = await fetch('https://opentdb.com/api_category.php')
        const categories = await data.json();
        console.log(categories.trivia_categories)
        setCategories(categories.trivia_categories)
    }

    const getImage = async (name) => {
        console.log(name)
        const q = name.split(' ').join('+')
        const img = await fetch(`https://pixabay.com/api/?key=apikey&q=${q}&image_type=photo`)
        const image = await img.json();
        console.log(image)
        setImage(image.previewURL)

    }
    return (
        <div className="categories">
            Yesss
            <div className="category-grid">
                {categories.map(category => (
                    <div className="category">
                        {category.name}
                        <img src={getImage(category.name)} /> //do not know what to do here to fetch image of the respective category 
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>


        </div>
    )
}

export default Category;
```

After changes suggested by Noah, I was able to show only one image.

```
const getImage = async (name) => {
        const query = stringMan(name.name)
        console.log(query)
        const img = await fetch(`https://pixabay.com/api/?key=17160673-fd37d255ded620179ba954ce0&q=${query}&image_type=photo`)
        const image = await img.json();
        console.log(image)
        setImage({ [name.name]: image.hits[0].largeImageURL })
    }
return (
        <div className="categories">
            Yesss
            <div className="category-grid">
                {categories.map(category => (
                    <div className="category" key={category.id}>
                        {category.name}
                        <img key={category.id} src={image[category.name]} />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of changes that you can make here.

One issue that I see is that you have a single `image` variable, that's being re-used for every single category. So when you map over a list of categories (for example let's say we have categories: [`history`, `science`, and `math`]). The current code will call getImage three times, with `history`, `science`, and `math` as parameters.

However, there is only **one** state variable that is being written to. Which means the last execution of `setImage` is the only one that will be preserved.

So, you might want to change `image` from being the URL of a category image, to an object that has the shape:

```
{
   history: [url],
   science: [url],
   math: [url]
}
```

The other change to make is that you are calling the `getImage()` function directly in the rendered output `<img src={getImage(category.name)} />`. Instead, this should simply use the value that was assigned to the image state: `<img src={image} />`.

To actually *fetch* the image, you can use the `useEffect` hook (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to react to changes to the categories variable. That might look something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
   categories.forEach((c) => getImage(c));
}, [categories]);
```

The `useEffect` hook will invoke the function it is given, whenever the dependencies change. This will allow you to trigger the `getImage` function in response to changes to the categories.

Comment: so if I make the image state, a key-value pair, how would I access the url inside the img tag?

Comment: It could look something like: `<img src={images[category.name]} />` assuming `images` is the name of the variable that holds the map of category to image name.

Comment: Okay I tried that, but it only displays one image. I don't understand why

Comment: I have added the changes in the question, can you check and tell me what is wrong here?
Oh and the stringMan() function is suggesting adding + instead a space in the category name, because the API accepts the multi word category like that.

Answer (score 0):

There're lot of improvement that could be done as stated by @noah-callaway above/below but coming straight to the point you need to simply fix the URI creation logic to use `encodeURIComponent` like below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function Category() {

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    getImage();
}, []);

const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
const [image, setImage] = useState('');

const fetchData = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('https://opentdb.com/api_category.php')
    const categories = await data.json();
    console.log(categories.trivia_categories)
    setCategories(categories.trivia_categories)
}

const getImage = async (name) => {
    return encodeURI(`https://pixabay.com/api/?key=apikey&q=${encodeURIComponent(name)}&image_type=photo`)
}
return (
    <div className="categories">
        Yesss
        <div className="category-grid">
            {categories.map(category => (
                <div className="category">
                    {category.name}
                    <img src={getImage(category.name)} />
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>


    </div>
)
}
```

don't have the api key so can't test but it'll give you something like

```
https://pixabay.com/api/?key=apikey&q=Entertainment%3A%20Comics&image_type=photo
```

good luck, hope it works.

Comment: But the API wouldn't support that URL